# SimpleCov overhead in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, code-coverage, simplecov

I was wondering what the overhead for simplecov is on Rails. It doesn't seem too heavy. I'm wondering if other people have negative experiences.

Comment: You mean overhead during test right ?

Answer (score 2):

I've used simplecov on multiple projects and have never noticed a significant slowdown.

The project in front of me uses Ruby 2.3.1 and simplecov 0.11.2. I'm on an old laptop with recent Mac OS X. The test suite has 1168 RSpec examples, 31 Cucumber scenarios and a handful of Jasmine tests (which simplecov doesn't see).

Test suite runtime with simplecov:

```
> time bin/rake RAILS_ENV=test
41.456u 5.429s 1:07.83 69.0%    0+0k 55+259io 137pf+0w
```

Test suite runtime without simplecov (`require 'simplecov'` commented out):

```
39.833u 5.626s 1:18.22 58.1%    0+0k 104+88io 204pf+0w
```

About 1.5 seconds' difference. Well worth it given the value of coverage results.

Comment: That's similar to what I get. Just wondering if someone had a negative experience